# Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1

my dll was created to target of .Net4.5 framework and i add to windows phone 8.1 project but at run time i am getting the error from my library files is

`Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: A phone uses a very different version of the CLR and cannot use a class library that targets the much bigger desktop version.  Create a Portable class library instead.  Having trouble getting your class library code to be portable is expected, the compiler tells you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your DLL was created for .NET 4.5, make sure that all the solutions in your project target that as well -the full platform, not the Client Profile, that's always a headache.